# Select single object from a query

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following query that pulls the data I need perfectly fine.

```
var subFuncName = from a in m_dcSQL_ConnectionProdTest.DC3_SubFunctions
                      where a.VersionIndex == versionIndex && stepDistinct.Select(b => b.Step).Contains(a.FunctionNumber) && stepDistinct.Select(c => c.LogID).Contains(a.SubFunctionNumber)
                      select new
                         {
                             a.FunctionNumber,
                             a.SubFunctionNumber,
                             a.SubFunctionName,
                         };
```

Then I want to add some data to a list.

```
foreach (var item in stepDistinct)
{
      lstPareto.Add(new clsPareto(Convert.ToInt32(item.Step), Convert.ToInt32(item.LogID),
      stepLogID.Where(p => p.Step.Equals(item.Step) && p.LogID.Equals(item.LogID)).Count(),
      subFuncName.Where(x => x.FunctionNumber.Equals(item.Step) && x.SubFunctionNumber.Equals(item.LogID)).Select(x => x.SubFunctionName).ToString())); --THIS LINE IS THE PROBLEM--
}
```

My clsPareto class:

```
public class clsPareto
    {       
        public int intStep { get; set; }
        public int intLogID { get; set; }
        public int iCount { get; set; }
        public string strFuncName { get; set; }

        public clsPareto(int ParetoStep, int ParetoLogID, int Count, string FuncName)
        {
            intStep = ParetoStep;
            intLogID = ParetoLogID;
            iCount = Count;
            strFuncName = FuncName;
        }        
    }
```

What I am trying to do, is to pull each SubFunctionName from subFuncName where FunctionNumber = Step and SubFunctionNumber = LogID. However, when I bind it to my datagrid, the column meant to show the names just shows the SQL Query String instead and doesn't actually take the elements I want. I thought my `.Select(x => x.SubFunctionName)` would do the trick, but apparently it doesn't. Still pretty new to using LINQ and C#, so how would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linq for the problem line is still an expression - `Select()` returns an `IEnumerable` not the value - and then you are doing a `ToString()` on it. This is why you just get SQL back.

You need to resolve the expression and get an actual object out of it. Adding [`Single()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb155325(v=vs.100).aspx) to get the FuncName should do it. You may also not need to convert to string if FuncName already is:

```
subFuncName.Where(x => x.FunctionNumber.Equals(item.Step) && x.SubFunctionNumber.Equals(item.LogID))
    .Select(x => x.SubFunctionName).Single().ToString()));
```

Comment: Well, that was insanely simple haha. Thanks a lot Rhumborl for your quick answer, it's working the way it should now!

Answer (score 0):

This solution will throw an exception if there is no matching element in the collection.

```
subFuncName.Where(x => x.FunctionNumber.Equals(item.Step) && x.SubFunctionNumber.Equals(item.LogID))
    .Select(x => x.SubFunctionName).Single().ToString()));
```

Could use;

```
 var subFuncName = subFuncName.Where(x => x.FunctionNumber.Equals(item.Step) && x.SubFunctionNumber.Equals(item.LogID))
        .Select(x => x.SubFunctionName).FirstOrDefault());

  if(subFuncName != null)
     // Add it
   else
     subFuncName == "UNDEFINED";
```

and handle the case if subFuncName is null yourself.